# Log Shipping Fails with CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR

Tags: log-shipping, disaster-recovery

DR plan for primary database in a private hosted cloud environment. The primary is a hosted physical server. The secondary is on another network, same domain. Version is SQL Server 2008R2 (10.50.2550.0) Enterprise. Compatibility=2008.

Log Shipping runs fine for a few restores, then I come back the next day, and I see "A previous RESTORE WITH CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR operation left the database in a potentially damaged state." And the restore job continues to fail. No further restores go through.

I checked the primary db with DBCC CHECKDB and there are no errors reported. I reconfigured LS twice, and the last time, added a 5-minute delay for the restore job. Same thing happens every time. It runs fine for a few restores, but then fails.

I could really use some help knowing where to look for the issue.

Graeme 
PS: This question was previously posted on SQL Server Central, with no responses. At the request of an expert, I am moving it here. Thanks again.

Comment: More detail: primary backs up to a SAN on the hosted network. Secondary (ls copy job) copies from SAN to a NAS share on the local network. Secondary restores from the NAS share. Permissions between SQL Servers are SQL. Permissions on files/folders are AD permissions.

Comment: Incidentally, an almost identical (except for the servers and the database) log shipping configuration has been running fine for a year or so. Same hosted environment, same SAN, NAS.

Comment: Thanks @PJMahoney - Are you talking a mid-flight FULL RESTORE? Then start up the jobs again? Otherwise, the LS I configured started with a full in standby mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a FULL backup of the primary DB (now or whenever), copy that backup file over to the secondary server, then restore that to the secondary DB in standby mode.

Afterwards, see if your LS jobs run successfully on secondary once you get enough fresh logs to apply to it.

Comment: I will give it a shot and let you know. Thanks for looking.

Comment: I restored a recent FULL and one DIFF in STANDBY mode. Then I reconfigured log shipping, and the only difference is that I used DNS names, instead of IP addresses. (We recently added the Hosted environment to our Domain.) Somehow, it's all working. I compared the old configuration with the new (scripted), and that's the only major difference I can find. Of course SSMS scripting of a Log Shipping configuration leaves a lot to be desired.